# Python multithreading, workers behaving wierd when items are queued from a file

Tags: python, multithreading

Below is my test program. My numberfile.txt contains a single column of numbers from 1 to 50. My expectation is 1 shouldnt be printed but it is getting printed. If I changed the input to a list of integers from 1 to 50 instead of reading from a file, 1 is not getting printed. Could someone help me understaing this strange behaviour.

```
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue

inputfile = "numberfile.txt"

NUM_WORKERS = 5
q = Queue()

def test(item):
    if item == '1':
        return
    print item

def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        test(item)
        q.task_done()

def main():

    for _ in range(NUM_WORKERS):
        t = Thread(target=worker)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
    with open(inputfile,'r') as f:
        line = f.readline()
        while line:
            q.put(line)
            line = f.readline()

    q.join()
```

output:

```
1
2


3
.
.
.
50
```

Comment: You are aware that `1 != '1'`, right?

Comment: Yeah I suspected that first and tried the condition ```item == 1``` it still didnt work. Also this is a dummy program to showcase the issue. My original problem is I am reading from a record file and doing some work on each line and I needed to skip the header of that file.

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve], there's no way around it. Also, make sure you determine whether multithreading is involved or not. Further, step through the code with a debugger and inspect the current state to find out where something goes wrong. Lastly, in case you didn't already, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Readline (or `for ln in f`) returns a string *including* the end-of-line character. For example:

```
> cat foo
1
2
3
4
5
```

So:

```
In [7]: with open('foo') as f: 
   ...:     for ln in f: 
   ...:         for c in ln: 
   ...:             print(ord(c), end=' ') 
   ...:         print() 
   ...:                                                                                                  
49 10 
50 10 
51 10 
52 10 
53 10 

In [8]: chr(10)                                                                                          
Out[8]: '\n'
```

A possible solution is to `strip()` the line before comparing it.